# Facing an issue while creating the pivot table using Pandas with Data frames. tried with xlwings , but getting different error regarding number format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, xlwings

My goal is to create Pivot table in the below format using Python.

[image: required pivot table type].

We need to create pivot table in above hierarchy. I tried the below code using `Pandas`, but didn't find any solution to recreate the required hierarchy. 
Code for reference below;

```
`df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['ROC | Channel Type', 'Revised Request Type', 'Reference Number', 'ROC | Country name'], values=['Pre Production Actual', 'Pre-Prod Target Tat'])`
```

I used xlwings as well using [Automate Excel with Python Pivot Table](https://towardsdatascience.com/automate-excel-with-python-pivot-table-899eab993966), but I'm getting `Number Format` issues. I tried using all these number formats [Excel Number Formats](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/ExcelNumFormat.html), but this didn't help.

Error text for reference;

```
line 32077, in AddDataField
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(2122, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((9, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Field
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

My goal is to create table by adding multiple rows and values using Python.
Please let me know If I want to update anything here.

[image]

Comment: If you want an actual pivot table in Excel, you can't use pandas.

Comment: In which way I can try, any other way except xlwings?

Comment: You could look into openpyxl or xlsxwriter, or fix the error in xlwings.

Comment: As far as I know using openpyxl we can't create any pivot, but we can refresh. In above code I am using xlsx writer only with pandas . writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename_pivot, engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay"). It will be helpfull If you give me solution for xlwings error. tried my best with differernt format, but didn't help

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your xlwings attempt.

Comment: Code is bit lengthy, https://towardsdatascience.com/automate-excel-with-python-pivot-table-899eab993966. used this code only.                                               pt_fields = [['Pre Production Actual', 'Pre Production Actual', win32c.xlSum, '@'],
                 ['Pre-Prod Target Tat', 'Pre-Prod Target Tat', win32c.xlSum, '@']].                      in this step code is failing, tried with different number formats, like General, 0, 0.0 ..etc

Comment: That [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/automate-excel-with-python-pivot-table-899eab993966) is not Xlwings, it's win32com and we don't know what your raw data is.

Comment: Sorry, Issue fixed.  pt_fields = [['Pre Production Actual', 'Pre Production Actual', win32c.xlSum, '@'], ['Pre-Prod Target Tat', 'Pre-Prod Target Tat', win32c.xlSum, '@']]                    While providing values, we need to give different names for source and target fields.  pt_fields = [['Pre Production Actual', ' sum Pre Production Actual', win32c.xlSum, '@'], ['Pre-Prod Target Tat', 'sum Pre-Prod Target Tat', win32c.xlSum, '@']]. This change filxed my issue. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. `pt_fields = [['Pre Production Actual', 'Pre Production Actual', win32c.xlSum, '0'], ['Pre-Prod Target Tat', 'Pre-Prod Target Tat', win32c.xlSum, '0']]` While providing values, we need to give different names for source and target fields. `pt_fields = [['Pre Production Actual', ' sum Pre Production Actual', win32c.xlSum, '0'], ['Pre-Prod Target Tat', 'sum Pre-Prod Target Tat', win32c.xlSum, '0']]`. This change filxed my issue.